# How to do a linq query with a IN

Tags: linq

I'm pretty new with linq and i would like to do this query :

```
select *
FROm dbo.PremiseProviders p
where p.premiseProviderId IN
  (select a.premiseproviderId
  FROM dbo.PremiseProviderAddresses a, dbo.premiseProviderAddressVersions v
  where a.premiseprovideraddressId = v.premiseprovideraddressId
  and v.postcode = '84280')
```

But i have no idea how to do the IN part, with the second Select, can someone help?
Thx

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Actually i have no idea of the syntax, i found that maybe i can use "contains" but it seems to be more for a list, not for a sub select

Comment: You can use the Contains() method after your embeded query, this is working with an IEnumerable interface (List, Dictionnary, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `Contains` method is translated into `IN` operator. E.g. you have collection of integers `2, 3, 7` then

```
   where ids.Contains(p.premiseProviderId)
```

Will be translated to

```
   WHERE p.premiseProviderId IN (@p1, @p2, @p3)
```

But EF is pretty clever and same approach with your query

```
from p in db.PremiseProviders
where (from a in db.PremiseProvideAddresses
       join v in db.PremiseProviderAddressVersions
           on a.premiseprovideraddressId equals v.premiseprovideraddressId
       where v.postcode == "84280"
       select a.premiseproviderId).Contains(p.premiseProviderId)
select p
```

Will be translated into better SQL than you have - it will generate `EXISTS` subquery. Something like

```
SELECT [t0].[premiseProviderId], [t0].[Foo], [t0].[Bar]
FROM [PremiseProviders] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [PremiseProvideAddresses] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [PremiseProviderAddressVersions] AS [t2]
       ON [t1].[premiseprovideraddressId] = [t2].[premiseprovideraddressId]
    WHERE [t0].[postcode] = @p1 AND 
          [t1].[premiseproviderId] = [t0].[premiseproviderId]
    )
```

For readability you can extract subquery definition into separate variable:

```
var providerIds = 
       from a in db.PremiseProvideAddresses
       join v in db.PremiseProviderAddressVersions
           on a.premiseprovideraddressId equals v.premiseprovideraddressId
       where v.postcode == "84280"
       select a.premiseproviderId;

var providers = from p in db.PremiseProviders
                where providerIds.Contains(p.premiseProviderId)
                select p;
```

NOTE: If instead of subquery you will pass result of query execution (i.e. save ids to list or array, then `IN` operator will be generated just as in first sample in my answer).

Comment: +1 for a better explanation of the translation of the query! :)

Answer (score 1):

First get all the `premiseProviderId` results for given postcode. Then filter the providers that have an `PermiseProviderId` that exists in the former result:

```
var providersIDs = (from a in dbo.PremiseProviderAddresses
                    join v in dbo.premiseProviderAddressVersions
                    on a.premiseprovideraddressId equals v.premiseprovideraddressId
                    where v.postcode == "84280"
                    select a.premiseproviderId).ToList();

var result = dbo.PremiseProviders.Where(x => providersIDs.Contains(x.PremiseProviderId));
```

Comment: Also correct, but as I pointed in my answer, this will be translated into `WHERE x.PremiseProviderId IN (@p1, @p2, @p3 ... @p1000)` if there is many items in `providers` list, then many parameters will be passed

Comment: So what you mean to say is that if I don't use the method-syntax, a better SQL query is generated? [This is not an offence, but I didn't now this, so I want to be sure I understand correctly :)]

Comment: Well, that depends. At least there will be two queries, and you should pass results of first query back to server. So, this *might* be some performance hit :)

Answer (score 0):

First you select the premiseProviderIds for postcode = 84280 (lets call it premiseProviderIdsForPostcode84280.

Then you do something like:

```
var query = from p in dbo.PremiseProviders
                   where premiseProviderIdsForPostcode84280.Contains(p.premiseProviderId)
                   select p;
```